# How to proper use tagging system in search?

Tags: discussion, search

When I'm adding multiples tags, it seems only somes are used, without any notice or error message.

Am I missing an important thing or a missing patchnote ?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: I goes to Drupal questions, then trying to apply multiple tags. Here's the link https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/8%20views%20datetime%20location?sort=Newest&edited=true

Comment: It seems that it uses a "AND" condition, is there a way to transform it to "OR" ?

Comment: Better edit your question to add this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [help pages on search](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/searching). You can reach them from the advanced search tips accordion on the search page.

> #### OR operator
>
> To combine results from multiple tags, separate the tag names (enclosed in square brackets) with the word "or": `[widgets] or [geegaws]` returns questions tagged with either tag.

Comment: Oh crap, I've search for that page for hours ... Thanks Leymannx !